# Render to template and get a response

Tags: python, django, django-templates, rendering

I have a situation like , I am fetching some html from db which is like this which is store in a variable **html**,

```
{{HEADER}} </br>
Hello {{NAME}}, </br>
{{FOOTER}}
```

AS you can see I have define data in such a way , *so that variables (HEADER ,FOOTER etc.) can be replace by there actual values* when I render this to any template.
But this is not happening .
 I have made a template abc.html in which I am rendering , and the content of this template is **{{html}}** , which is replaced by above code when i render to this template.

I have tried this --

```
html_content =TemplateResponse(request,"abc.html",{'html':html,'HEADER':html_header,'FOOTER':html_footer})
html_content.render()
```

Now the problem is , in abc.html only html is replace by its values , but the variables defined in html like HEADER , FOOTER is not replace by its content.

I know it is something complex and may not be possible .

But can any one suggest me some way , so that I can change the variables in template

Comment: Did you try to `mark_safe` the html variable?

Comment: Your html variable contains this value?
{{HEADER}} </br>
Hello {{NAME}}, </br>
{{FOOTER}}

Comment: @matino  NO , I haven't tried this

Comment: @Sudipta  , Yes it is . and when I render to abc.html , {{html}} replace by there value but header footer doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because the final html template is rendered only once. While rendering abc.html, it looks for all template variables and replaces them. In this case only 'html' got replaced by its value. And then the html got rendered because it doesn't find any other variable or included html.

If you are passing a template variable inside another template variable, then it will not get rendered.

You can do something like this:

```
#abc.html
{{HEADER}}
{{ CONTENT }}
{{FOOTER}}

#in view
html_content =TemplateResponse(request,"abc.html {'CONTENT':html_content,'HEADER':html_header,'FOOTER':html_footer})
```

For this you need to make changes in the format of html in database.

But as you said, in your case there can be many template variables apart from header and footer, then you can update the 'html' variable before sending it for render.

```
finalhtml = html.replace('{{HEADER}}',html_header).replace('{{FOOTER}}',html_footer)
html_content =TemplateResponse(request,"abc.html {'html':finalhtml})
```

Or you can use:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
t = Template(html)
c = Context({'HEADER':html_header,'FOOTER':html_footer})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I guess this one is the cleanest way to do it; i.e. loading the template from string rather than a file. [See documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system).

Comment: Thanks for reply , the way you suggest doesn't work for me because in Html I can define more variables then just header and footer.

Comment: Ok. Then use replace() function before sending the 'html' variable for rendering.
`finalhtml = html.replace('{{HEADER}}',html_header).replace('{{FOOTER}}',html_footer)`

Comment: I am also thinking of using same thing

Comment: @Inforian You can directly load the template from a string, instead of a html file. I have added the solution in an edit.